# firebase error TS7006: Parameter 'snapshot' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tslint

I am getting following lint error:

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'snapshot' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

on following firebase cloud function:

```
exports.createTeamMember = functions.firestore
  .document(`teamProfile/{teamId}/teamMemberList/{newUserId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const id: string = snapshot.data().id;
    const email: string = snapshot.data().email;
    const teamId: string = snapshot.data().teamId;
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using TSLint, must provide type for the arguments `snapshot` and `context` as follows:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { EventContext } from 'firebase-functions';

exports.createTeamMember = functions.firestore
  .document(`teamProfile/{teamId}/teamMemberList/{newUserId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snapshot: admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot, context: EventContext) => {
    const id: string = snapshot.data().id;
    const email: string = snapshot.data().email;
    const teamId: string = snapshot.data().teamId;
  });
```